# Partner users can't see its customers custom object records

Tags: custom-object, customer-portal, partner-portal, high-volume-portal

We have a Partner that has several customers that it supports.  We have a custom object called Change.  We also user the high-volume portal license for some of the customer users and the customer portal manager custom license for some of the customer users.

If a customer user with the high-volume license creates a Change record, the Partner cannot see the record.  If a customer user with the customer portal manager custom license creates a Change record, the Partner can see the record.

How do we get the Partner to see the custom records raised by the high-volume license?  It works with the Standard Object Cases, just need the same capability to roll over to the custom object